# My desktop does not show up on my monitor on Debian 9

Tags: debian, xfce, desktop

I've had Debian 9 for a while now with Xfce4. Recently the desktop has stopped appearing after I log in. It's just grey. How do I get my desktop back on my monitor?

Answer (score 2):

I ran `xfdesktop` in terminal. My desktop has reappeared on my monitor. It remained there even after logging out and in, and after rebooting.